# Django simple math captcha , how to pass question_tmpl as placeholder

Tags: django, package, captcha

When using simple math catpcha , how can define a custom value to be displayed, the default is this one

```
"What is %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?"
```

And I want to pass it as the placeholder , I did this

```
self.fields['captcha'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = = "What is %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?"
```

But It doesnt return the numbers, but the whole string, it renders What is %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?, but i want it to show like Whats is 5 + 3, any ideas why isnt it working ?

Comment: You are using == instead of =, so that last line of code is just checking for equality.  But according to the documentation, your display value is already the default value, so you don't need to specify it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-math-captcha

Comment: The == was a writing error sorry, right, but the value is shown in a label , and i want to show it as the placeholder of the input

Comment: I've never used it, the documentation is pretty light, but if you haven't yet, look at the link.

Comment: I'm the author of django-simple-math-captcha. Setting the placeholder is something that is not easily accomplished with the current code. You're probably best off setting the placeholder via JavaScript, and your use case brings up a good change to implement; I'll see if I can work it in.